wiring two generators interlock kit, main panel and subpanel
Can I wire the main panel with an interlock kit with 1 generator another interlock kit to subpanel for second generator?

Maybe.  A better question might be why.  Can usually put most of the essential/critical circuits on one panel and use one generator.  Two gens usually use twice as much fuel and half the stuff in a house is usually not needed for hours/a couple of days.

It would be better if you could describe your goals first and then ask whether your proposal would achieve them.  The answer is almost certainly that yes, you can do that.  However, doing it might not achieve what you want.  In particular, the subpanel interlock might not trigger if the main panel has power.  Is that a problem?  Why two generators?  Are the interlocks manual or automatic?

This question was asked and answered yesterday.

An interlock is manual.  Before starting the main generator you would have to switch off the subpanel.  But switching off all your big loads is a normal and required part of using a manual interlock.
